# How to get the headers of a reponse in a fetch request?

Tags: reactjs, redux, http-headers, fetch, response

I'm trying to get the headers of a response following a fetch request and to assign some values to my redux state. I can only get access to the promise of the headers though. I would appreciate some help on figuring out why.

```
export function sign_in(email, password){
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGGING_USER_IN' });    
    return fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in" ,{
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    })
    .then(response => { 
        dispatch({type:'LOGGING_USER_IN_SUCCESS', payload: response.headers})
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        dispatch({type:'LOGGING_USER_IN_FAILURE', payload: error, error:true})
    })
}    
};
```

My reducer:

```
export default function authReducer(state = {
isLoaded: false,
}, action) {

switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGING_USER_IN':
        return  {
            ...state,
        }

    case 'LOGGING_USER_IN_SUCCESS':
        // console.log(action.payload.get("access-token"))
        return  {
            // ...state,
            isLoaded: true,
            user: action.payload}

    case 'LOGGING_USER_IN_FAILURE':
        return{
            ...state,
            isLoaded: true,
            errorMessage: action.payload.message}

    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

Comment: looks correct, any errors ?

Comment: my state always ends up empty. when I try to console.log response.headers, I got am empty value as well. That's why I believe I'm just getting the promise and the the real headers.
Besides that no errors. my headers are good according to my browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.headers` is a `Headers{}` object that represents the HTTP response headers.

You need to lookup the headers that you want to dispatch by calling `get(name)`, or you can get all the headers by using `forEach` like this:

```
.then(response => {
    const payload = {};
    response.headers.forEach((value, name) => payload[name] = value);
    dispatch({type:'LOGGING_USER_IN_SUCCESS', payload })
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snow-7bums)

A side note:
Only the following headers are exposed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

So if you want to access any other headers, you will need to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header appropriately.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is helpful. I'm actually trying to get my access token. As such I tried response.headers.get("access-token") but I get a null.
When using your code, I indeed cannot see an access token in my Headers{} object. Is there a reason why? (I see it in my broswer's network response)

Comment: That's probably because you haven't set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, because by default only some of the headers are exposed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Yes, you were correct. My issue was with exposing the headers. Thank you so much for the help!